# Compare dictionaries from different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The problem I have is a bit far-fetched, but I will try to express it as clearly as I can.

I have two python files that contain different dictionaries.

In the file `science.py` the result of the dictionary is as follows:

```
    dict1 = { "microbiome": {
                  "lang": "en",
                  "lemmatizer": "microbiome",
                  "Wikidata": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1330402"
                  "DBpedia": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota"
          }, "teaching innovation": {
                 "lang": "en",
                 "lemmatizer": "innovación docente",
                 "Wikidata": null,
                 "DBpedia": null
              },
               ...... 
          }
```

The content of the structure of this dictionary is built in a function that I have called `process (word)`.

The output of the `compact.py` file is as follows:

```
    dict2 = { http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota :[
                 {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'}, 
                 {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'}, 
                 {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'}],
             'teaching innovation': [{'keyword': 'Semantics', 
                                     'language': 'en'},
                        {'keyword': 'Semàntica', 'language': 'ca'},
                        {'keyword': 'Semántica lingüística', 
                        'language': 'es'}],
            .... }
```

The content of the structure of this dictionary is built by means of a function called `query_kw (uri)` where a query is made to the DBpedia page to get the translations of the word from the uri. This returns a list with the different translations of the word in the form of dictionaries.

As seen in `dict2`, it contains translations of a word along with the language they are in. What I am trying to do is check if the word from `dict1` is found in `dict2`.
In the small example that I have put above you can see. If we look at `dict1` a dictionary key is" microbiome "then I have to check if it is in the dictionary list of `dict2`. If it is not found as is the case then add it to the `dict2` list in the same way as the others (`{'keyword': microbiome, 'language': 'en'}`).

Then the result would have to be the following:

```
           dict2 = { http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota :[
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'}, 
                        {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'},
                        {'keyword': 'microbiome', 'language': 'en'}],
                    'teaching innovation': [{'keyword': 'Semantics', 
                                          'language': 'en'},
                        {'keyword': 'Semàntica', 'language': 'ca'},
                        {'keyword': 'Semántica lingüística', 
                                     'language': 'es'}],
                        {'keyword': 'teaching innovation', 
                                     'language': 'en'}],
                 .... }
```

What I have tried has been the following (I know it is not optimal but it was to have an idea of ​​how I can do it):

```
wrapper = query_kw(uri)
res_keys = process(palabra)
for k in rest_keys.keys():
    wrap = {'keyword': rest_keys[k], 'language': rest_keys[k]['language']
    for ind in wrapper:
        for key, value in wrapper[ind]:
            for ky, v in wrap:  
                if key is not ky and value is not v:
                    wrapper.append(wrap)
```

I already said, it is not beautiful to see nor is it optimal and above all it does not work correctly, but I can not think of how to do it. I hope I have explained myself well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've put up this short script, you can run the full code to verify it applied to the sample in your question.

Basically I use a dict comprehension, and use the `DBpedia` as the key that correlates both dictionaries.

Let me know if you have questions (and if this is what you intended).

```
def merge_dicts(dict1, dict2):
    # Assuming every item on dict1 has a `DBpedia` key and a `lang` key
    new_items = {items['DBpedia']: [{'keyword': key, 'language': items['lang']}] for key, items in dict1.items()}
    for url, new_item_list in new_items.items():
        # Assuming every item on dict2 has the `DBpedia` url as keys
        for item in dict2[url]:
            found = False
            for new_item in new_item_list:
                if item['keyword'].strip().lower() == new_item['keyword'].strip().lower():
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                break
        if not found:
            dict2[url].append(new_item)

    return dict2

dict1 = { "microbiome": {
          "lang": "en",
          "lemmatizer": "microbiome",
          "Wikidata": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1330402",
          "DBpedia": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota"
    }
}
        
dict2 = { 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microbiota' :[
     {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'ca'}, 
     {'keyword': 'Microbiota', 'language': 'en'}, 
     {'keyword': 'Microbioma', 'language': 'es'}
     ]
     }

print(merge_dicts(dict1, dict2))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need but I don't understand why it doesn't write anything in the list when it should in some cases. In addition, there are some cases that as a URI of the word is not found, it is returned as a dictionary identifier. I will edit the question and put the example I say.

Comment: Do you mean `"DBpedia": None` ? (instead of `"DBpedia": null`)

Comment: @drakitus98 are you there ?

Comment: Hi i'm sorry. I finally managed to fix the problem, but I approached it in a different way. What I have done has been to compare the result of the first dictionary using a function that I have that builds the dictionary with the result that the query on DBpedia gave me. Once compared, I added them to a list. It has helped me a lot what you have taught me thank you so much!